# Arduino has a delay in dialogue with Android

Tags: android, arduino, adk

I'm testing an Arduino MEGA ADK connected with a tablet with Android 3.2 (Archos 80 G9) and I've note a strange delay.

I've made a simple program for Arduino to find the cause of the problem and I've noticed that if I comment the line `acc.write(data, 3);` than the out #22 turn on or off when I change the input pin #6. On the other hand, with the line `acc.write(data, 3);` the out pin #22 have a random delay.
Is it normal? Can I avoid this delay?

Here is my test code:

```
#include <Usb.h>
#include <AndroidAccessory.h>

AndroidAccessory acc("Google, Inc.",
             "DemoKit",
             "DemoKit Arduino Board",
             "1.0",
             "http://www.android.com",
             "0000000012345678");

int precVal = 0;

const int inPin = 6;

void init_leds()
{
    pinMode(inPin, INPUT);

    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(22, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("\r\nStart");
  init_leds();
  acc.powerOn();
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);

  int val = digitalRead(inPin);   // read the input pin
  digitalWrite(22, val);

  byte data[3];

  if (acc.isConnected()) {
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);  //connected
    int len = acc.read(data, sizeof(data), 1);
    if (len > 0) {
       digitalWrite(data[1], data[2] ? HIGH : LOW);
    }

    if (val != precVal) {
        data[0] = 0x1;
    data[1] = 0;
    data[2] = val ? 1 : 0;
    acc.write(data, 3);
    precVal = val;
    }
  } else {
     digitalWrite(12, LOW);
  }
}
```